# Eclipse android phonegap config.xml not working?

Tags: android, xml, web-applications, cordova

I can't for the life of me figure out why my XML file isn't working. It's located in my assets www folder: The links to the images are correct - the id of my application is the same, but it still won't show my splash screen OR icon!

Help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id = "com.phonegap.helloword"
    version = "1.0.0">

    <name>Testerm Application</name>

    <description>
    A test application for PhoneGap
    </description>

    <author href="graemeleighfield@infinitegroup.co.uk" email="graemeleighfield@infinitegroup.co.uk">
    Graeme Leighfield
    </author>

    <icon src="img/icon.png" width="72" height="72" ></icon>

    <gap:spalsh src="img/ash.jpg"/>

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: I noticed that gap:spalsh is mis-spelled? Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graeme, are you building localy in eclipse?

If yes, then config.xml and shouldnt' work at all -- it's for http://build.phonegap.com only -- not for your local development.

Answer (score 7):

Yes the config.xml is only for build.phonegap.com.

### For building with Eclipse:

Create a slash screen with splash.png filename in the res/drawable-hdpi folder.
Add super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash) to your App.java file.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

Comment: I think your answer is even better.

Comment: This currently works, but throws the following debug message - `Setting integer properties in DroidGap will be deprecated in 3.1 on August 2013, please use config.xml`